# Is it possible to get an address of a struct in the Library or Contract without using mapping?

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity, struct, library, memory

[Q] I was wondering is it possible to get an address of a struct on the memory space? Inside `initialise()` function after the `Node` object creation, I want to get is address if it is possible. Since between contracts I can only transfer its address value.

Thank you for your valuable time and help.

```
library LinkedList {
    uint80 constant None = uint80(0); /// NULL value.                                                           

    struct data {
        Node head;
        Node[] node_array;
    }

    struct Node {
        string data;
        uint80 prev;
        uint80 next;
    }

    function initialize(data storage self){
        self.head = Node({prev: None, next: None, data: "",});
        self.head.next = /// self.head's address.        
    }        
}
```

Inside `initialize()` following code piece works:

```
Node s = self.node_array[index];
uint addr;
assembly {
    addr := s
}
```

Inside `initialize()` the following code piece does not work:

> Error: Expected elementary inline assembly operation.

```
self.head = Node({prev: None, next: None, data: 10,});

uint addr;
assembly {
    addr := self.head   
}
```

or

```
Node new_node;
new_node.data = d;
new_node.next = h.next;
new_node.prev = h.own;

uint newnode_addr;
assembly {
   newnode_addr := new_node
}
```

`newnode_addr` returns 0 instead of a valid address.

I am not able to do following assignment also:

> Error: Type struct Node memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type struct Node storage pointer.

```
Node newnode = Node({prev: None, next: None, data: 10,});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to get a pointer to the struct? Are you trying to get a copy of that struct into another contract? Is this what you're meaning by `between contracts I can only transfer its address value`?

You can write constant functions which can query the state of a given contract, and will easily allow you to expose the node memory to other contracts. For example `getDataForNode(i)` which can return the data field of a given node at index i.